# Extracting contents from a PDF to display on web pages

Tags: html, python-3.x, pdf, web, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to display the contents of the pdf by converting PDF into HTML using Adobe Acrobat 2021, extracting the paragraph structure, and post-processing. I saw a website whose only source is judgments as PDFs from the Supreme Court Website and displays them flawlessly. Does anybody have any idea how it's done?

My current flow is to convert the PDF into HTML to preserve the page layout and extract the text using Beautifulsoup.
Issues I'm currently facing:

- Bulletin numbers are somehow dynamically calculated in the PDF and are tagged as

```
::before
```

on the browser. bs4 won't recognize it

- Miss some paragraphs in between as some paragraphs are detected incorrectly
- Table is detected as a table but some imperfections

PDF example : [drive link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Sobqym3RVjyaK9qid395khB9nOmZc0g0/view?usp=sharing)

HTML from Adobe Acrobat : [HTML file of the above PDF](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mfHEDnI7DTcWI4zORrMvVdcwG0B3cmJG/view?usp=sharing)

This is my goal : [Advocatekhoj](https://www.advocatekhoj.com/library/judgments/announcement.php?WID=13472)

This is how accurate I'm expecting it to be.
Could someone please shed light on this? how-to(s) or any suggestions.

Note: I tried various PDF to HTML tools and the Adobe Acrobat was the best in detecting paragraph layout and preserving structure.

```
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    from pprint import pprint 
    
    from os import listdir
    from os.path import isfile, join
    mypath = "sup_del_htmls/"
    onlyfiles = [f for f in listdir(mypath) if isfile(join(mypath, f))]
    counter = 0
    for f in onlyfiles:
        print(counter)
        with open("output_txt/"+f+".txt", 'w',encoding='utf-8') as txtfile:
            with open(mypath+f, encoding='utf-8') as fp:
                soup = BeautifulSoup(fp, "html.parser")
                
                para_counter = 1
                for li in soup.select("li"):
                    if li.find_parent("li"):
                        continue
                    
                    full_para = ""
                    for para in li.select("p"):
                        for match in para.findAll('span'):
                            match.unwrap()
                        para_txt = para.get_text().replace("¶", "")
                        para_txt = para_txt.strip()
                        if para_txt.endswith(".") or para_txt.endswith(":") or para_txt.endswith(";") or para_txt.endswith(",") or para_txt.endswith('"') or para_txt.endswith("'"):
                            full_para += para_txt + "\n"
                        else:
                            full_para += para_txt + " "
    
                    txtfile.write(full_para)
                    txtfile.write("\n" + "--sep--" + "\n")
                    if li.find("table"):
                        tables = li.find_all("table")
                        for table in tables:
                            txtfile.write("--table--"+ "\n")
                            txtfile.write(str(table) + "\n")
                            txtfile.write("--sep--" + "\n")
                reversed_end = []
                for p in reversed(soup.select("p")):
                    if p.find_parent('li') or p.find_parent('ol'):
                        break
                    reversed_end.append(" ".join(p.text.split()))
                if reversed_end!=[]:
                    for final_end in reversed(reversed_end):
                        txtfile.write(final_end + "\n")
                        txtfile.write("--sep--" + "\n")
```

The Result : [output.txt](https://drive.google.com/file/d/19qVA4eXjXO8ambBbwo0fkM3ouySh0INX/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Please read [ask] and provide a [mre].

Comment: Please include a sample of the html you're getting (it can be another drive link to the whole file and/or a relevant snippet), and a snippet of the current bs4 output that shows the part you're not happy with

Comment: Hi, @Driftr95 I've fixed it. Please ask me if you need anything else.

Answer (score 0):

For the numbering with `:before` in css, you can try to extract the selector/s for the numbered items with a function like this

```py
def getLctrSelectors(stsh):  
    stsh = stsh.get_text() if stsh else ''

    ll_ids = list(set([
        l.replace('>li', '> li').split('> li')[0].strip() 
        for l in stsh.splitlines() if l.strip()[:1] == '#' 
        and '> li' in l.replace('>li', '> li') and 
        'counter-increment' in l.split('{')[-1].split(':')[0]
    ]))
    for i, l in enumerate(ll_ids): 
        sel = f'{l} > li > *:first-child'
        ll_ids[i] = (sel, 1)
        crl = [
            ll for ll in stsh.splitlines() if ll.strip().startswith(l)
            and 'counter-reset' in ll.split('{')[-1].split(':')[-2:][0] 
        ][:1] 
        if not crl: continue
        
        crl = crl[0].split('{')[-1].split('counter-reset')[-1].split(':')[-1]
        crl = [w for w in crl.split(';')[0].split() if w.isdigit()] 
        ll_ids[i] = (sel, int(crl[-1]) if crl else 1)
    
    return ll_ids
```

(It should take a `style` tag as input and return a list of selectors and starting counts - like `[('#l1 > li > *:first-child', 3)]` for your sample html.)

You can use it in your code to insert the numbers into the text in the bs4 tree:

```py
                soup = BeautifulSoup(fp, "html.parser") 
                for sel, ctStart in getLctrSelectors(soup.select_one('style')):
                    for i, lif in enumerate(soup.select(sel)):
                        lif.insert(0, f'{i + ctStart}. ')
                
                para_counter = 1
                ### REST OF CODE ###
```

---

I'm not sure I can help you with paragraphs and tables issues... Are you sure the site uses the same pdfs as you have? (Or that they use pdfs at all rather than something closer to the original/raw data?) Your pdf itself looked rather different from its corresponding page on the site.